# Visual Studio Database custom criteria search wont work

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a database in Visual Studio and I am coding with VB.net I have created textboxes and checkboxes to match the fields that each will search when the search button is pressed .

whenever i perform a search using the text boxes and checkbox i get an error.
 `Item Name` , `Room` , `Broken`, `In Use`, `floor`, are the fields searched by the tehe text in `NameSearch`, `RoomSearch`, `BrokenSearchare`, `InUseSearch` ,`FloorSearch`respectivly ....etc

this is thee code for the search button

```
    Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

    RecordDataGridView.Refresh()
    Me.RecordBindingSource.Filter = "[Item Name]= '" & NameSearch.Text & "' And  [Room]= '" & RoomSearch.Text & "' And  [Make]= '" & MakeSearch.Text & _
        "' And  [Broken]= '" & BrokenSearch.CheckState & "' And  [Replaced]= '" & ReplacedSearch.CheckState & "'And [ID#]= '" & IdentificationNumberSearch.Text & _
        "' And   [Floor]= '" & FloorSearch.Text & "' And   [In Use]= '" & InUseSearch.CheckState & "'"
    Me.RecordTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MLGDatabaseDataSet.Record)
    RecordDataGridView.Refresh()

End Sub
```

[image: Data area]

[image: Search area]

the error

for example I enter a text into item nameSearch and floorSearch  and press search ,no result will be turned up as the other text boxes have no text in them.

Comment: @Christos sorry for the late reply . the error is that whenever is that if i enter a text into item `nameSearch` and `floorSearch` no result will be turned up as the other text boxes have no text in them . so i was hoping to find a way to check do something like `Me.RecordBindingSource.Filter = "[Item Name]= '" & NameSearch.Text & "' And '' Or [Room]= '" & RoomSearch.Text & "'......` using  (And Or) which can only work in this example when only 2 text boxes accept text to be searched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted the same thing as @competent_tech. I would set it up this way to make it easier to debug.

```
    Dim strFilter As String = _
            "[Item Name]= '" & NameSearch.Text & _
            "' And  [Room]= '" & RoomSearch.Text & _
            "' And  [Make]= '" & MakeSearch.Text & _
            "' And  [Broken]= '" & BrokenSearch.CheckState & _
            "' Or  [Replaced]= '" & ReplacedSearch.CheckState & _
            "' And [ID#]= '" & IdentificationNumberSearch.Text & _
            "' And   [Floor]= '" & FloorSearch.Text & _
            "' And   [In Use]= '" & InUseSearch.CheckState & "'"
    Debug.Print(strFilter)
    RecordBindingSource.Filter = strFilter
```

Edit: you want to filter only when there are conditions given

```
    'filter string
    Dim strFilter As String = ""

    'for check boxes you probably want to filter only if checked
    If BrokenSearch.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then strFilter += "And [Broken]= " & BrokenSearch.CheckState & " "
    If ReplacedSearch.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then strFilter += "And [Replaced]= " & ReplacedSearch.CheckState & " "
    If InUseSearch.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then strFilter += "And [In Use]= " & InUseSearch.CheckState & " "

    'for text boxes you want to filter only if has text
    If IdentificationNumberSearch.Text.Length > 0 Then strFilter += "And [ID#]= '" & IdentificationNumberSearch.Text & "' "
    If FloorSearch.Text.Length > 0 Then strFilter += "And [Floor]= " & FloorSearch.Text & " "
    If RoomSearch.Text.Length > 0 Then strFilter += "And [Room]= " & RoomSearch.Text & " "
    If MakeSearch.Text.Length > 0 Then strFilter += "And [Make]= '" & MakeSearch.Text & "' "
    If NameSearch.Text.Length > 0 Then strFilter += "And [Item Name]= '" & NameSearch.Text & "' "

    'check to make sure there is at least one condition
    If strFilter.Length > 0 Then

        'remove the first "And"
        strFilter = strFilter.Remove(0, 4)

        'output
        Debug.Print(strFilter)

        'set to filter
        RecordBindingSource.Filter = strFilter
    End If
```

Edit: Your error "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Boolean and System.String" I think the problem is that the filter value has to match the field type.

For strings do this: `[Make] = 'stringValue'` using single quotes;
For integers do this: `[Floor] = 24` without single quotes;
For bit do this: `[Broken] = 1` without single quotes;

It looks like Broken, Replaced and In Use are Bit type in the database. And I'm guessing that Floor and Room are Integer.

Comment: this method also makes coding easier . thanks.
there is still the issue of being forced to fill in all the search criteria because of the `And` when it should check `And Or` but i don't know how to go about accomplishing that

Comment: great code @D_Bester, the only issue is with the checkboxes , this error is returned whenever a search is performed after checking a checkbox  : `Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Boolean and System.String.`

Comment: the checkbox returns either true or false but i see you assigning strings to  all 3 checkboxes , well that part should not be too hard to fix . then again it could be a bit challenging

Comment: @AltCoder Which line gives the error? this one? Me.RecordTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MLGDatabaseDataSet.Record)     Also please post the output from Debug.Print(strFilter)

Comment: Check out the edited answer for the solution to: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Boolean and System.String

Comment: its working fine now , thank you . I hope many others find this code useful .

Answer (score 2):

Without addressing other issues, such as using a parameterized query to prevent SQL injections or using StringBuilder to more efficiently perform concatenation, I believe your issue may be a missing space in this snippet:

```
ReplacedSearch.CheckState & "'And [ID#]= '"
```

if you change this to

```
ReplacedSearch.CheckState & "' And [ID#]= '"
```

it may resolve the immediate error. However, you almost certainly have additional logic errors introduced by the OR statement in the middle (you probably want to surround the two clauses that are ORed with parentheses).

Comment: Possibly so , thanks . the other issue is that even if i perform a search without filling in all the textboxes and checking all the textboxes i will not get any search result because as you can see the `And` forces the user to fill in all the search criteria , this is a problem